# Facebook question closed as duplicate of earlier version, which was closed as NARQ

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question

My question, [Facebook likes constantly changing](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17736/facebook-likes-decreasing), was closed because it was ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form:

I [rewrote the question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17756/question-about-the-count-on-a-facebook-like-button)  with that in mind, and it was closed as being a 'Possible Duplicate'

But the question it's a duplicate of cannot be answered because it's closed.

Is there somebody kind enough to open it?

Comment: Even though the other question is closed, you can still edit it. You should do that and request it to be re-opened rather than creating a new question.

Comment: Thanks, Al. I did that, and I in the 'reason for edit' field I made a request that the thread be re-opened -- is that the correct place to request it's reopened?

Comment: Users can vote to re-open questions. You would be well-served to leave a comment on the question that you've made edits. There's not always a lot of momentum for re-open votes, so if you're not getting any traction that way you can flag the question for a Moderator.

Answer (score 2):

The new question wasn't sufficiently different from the original.

You should have edited/rewritten your original question and flagged that for moderator attention. We would have reviewed the edits and decided whether it was a better question. If it was it would have been reopened.